# Using macros in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using excel macros for the first time (VBA too).
I have data y=f(frequency) let's say 10 curves data all in the same sheet each one in a column (which is not the case, I have much more).
And I need to take only B, E and I column from the 10 column i got. 
My idea is to make an array that contains the letters B,E,I of the column i want to use, and after that use that array in a loop

`Dim T(26) As String
T=[H,L,A,CE,A.....]`

I think it will give me  (H,1) = (T(0),1)

The macro I created for one curve is the following
`Sub my_tuto_2()
'
' my_tuto_2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+f
'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=sheet!$C$1"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=sheet!$C$2:$C$29"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=sheet!$A$1"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=sheet!$A$2:$A$29"
End Sub`

In other words, I want to make the same but for 26 columns [H1,L1,AJ1,AX1,......ET1...] 
and this was the modification that i made which is not working.

`ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=sheet!$T(0)$2:$T(0)$29"`

which didn't work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The right modification would be

1- Using Array function (and use the letters of the desired columns

`Dim MesCol()
 MesCol = Array("B", "C", "E", "H", "I", "J")`

2- Use the following modification

`.Name = "=sheet_name!" & MesCol(i) & "1"
 .Values = "=sheet_name!" & MesCol(i) & "2:" & MesCol(i) & "29"`

3- Using a "for" loop